# how to call struts action from the jsp:include or tiles?

Tags: java, jsp-tags, struts-1

I have jsp, in which I want to include another jsp which is the forwarded result of struts action.

How I can include/insert using jsp:include/tiles insert or any other method?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it with struts1 or struts2??

Comment: Use the path of the action in jsp:include. Note that this violates the MVC architecture.

Comment: i tried using <jsp:include flush="true" page="login.do"></jsp:include> it is giving ServletException in [filepath]null can u please explain me using example

Comment: No. Try first explaining us, with your code, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I want to do like this <jsp:include page="/login.do" />, but it doesn't work for me. STack trace of exception is [ServletException in:/login.jsp] null'

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly. In your main JSP, You want to include a content which is a result of another action. I am not sure about jsp:include or tiles, but you can do this by using

1. For that first you have to add your action to global forwards like
   `name="beanIncFwd" path="/beanIncludeTest.do"`
2. Add action form corresponding ActionForm (for example `name="beanIncForm"`)
3. add the definition of action in action tag (for example I am using direct forward; you can use your own class here) `path="/beanIncAction"` and `forward="/mypage.jsp"`
4. Add the required classes (i.e. Action and ActionForm)
5. In your main JSP, write the following at the location where you want the included contents

   bean:include id="includePart" forward="beanIncFwd"/>
   bean:write name="includePart" filter="false"/>